# Need more slots on the panel Anyway to get around replacing the whole panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm swapping out a traditional hot water heater for a tankless. My house is old and has a double pole 20amp breaker (outside electrical panel). The tankless calls for 3 x 40DP im guessing that's 3 double pole 40 amp breakers. Space is the issue i have no slots left on the panel any tricks to keep from have to replace the whole panel [image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Maybe, but it'll depend on your panel.  We'll need to see some pictures of it, at the very least.  Try to include pics of the breakers, the labeling, and the wiring with the deadfront removed if you can.

Comment: Also, what size electrical service does this house have?  You're thinking of adding 100A, and a lot of houses only have 100 or 200A of power available.  You might need a service upgrade to install that heater, depending on what you have now.

Comment: See also this question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/215522/calculating-electrical-demand-for-new-construction-with-electric-tankless-water/

Comment: Yeah, I've run into that too and it's pretty annoying -- you'll have to resize the pics in some image editing program, or save it with higher compression, until the file size is small enough and then it'll let you upload them.  Or just upload them somewhere else on the internet and put a link.

Comment: This is opinion based, but I really don't like electric, on demand water heaters, they have limited flow rates, require incredible amounts of electricity when many areas have a stressed electrical grid.  Like Harp said in another post, new tank type water heaters are very well insulated and efficient. You could replace it with a similar type with no panel upgrades.   As others have said, you'll need to do load calculations to be sure you can support that. IE:  Electric range, clothes dryer, furnace? Adding a potential 120 amp draw is not trivial. We are here to help. get us more details.

Comment: Walter:  I assume you're using a smart phone for the pics.  I use a free app called PhotoCompress on my andriod phone and it works great. I hate it that all the new phones take these huge pictures and can't change the settings. Not only does it waste a lot of memory on the phone, you run into issues when trying to send/upload them.   Maybe I'll have to dig up my old flip phone ! LOL

Comment: @WalterMoose, the one picture I'd like that you didn't add is a picture of the panel's labeling -- it's usually on a sticker inside the door.  The reason I ask is because I can't tell for sure, but this very much looks like a 100A panel, in which case you're definitely not going to be able to add a 120A water heater to it at all, regardless of breaker spaces.

Comment: This is an extremely trendy, extremely bad idea. And extremely expensive by the time you upgrade not just the panel, but the service to the panel. Return it and get a tank type heater....

Comment: Why are you wanting to install a tankless heater to begin with?  And yes, can we have a photo of the labeling on the inside of the panel's door please?

Comment: We're trying to see the amp rating on the main breaker, the size and insulation type of the wire feeding it, and what is the load of the mystery tap ahead of the main breaker?

Comment: Thanks fellas. Like i said its an old house built in the 20s. Honestly how much ballpark figure would that cost to make the switch

Comment: @WalterMoose, without knowing who your utility is, how big your current service is, or how big of an upgrade you'd need, it's hard to give a precise answer.  I'd guess somewhere in the $2k-10k range.  If you give more details we might be able to narrow it down further, but honestly I agree with Ecnerwal: your best bet is probably going to be to return or sell the tankless you have and get a tank type water heater.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease, judging by the solar sticker on the meter housing next to the panel, I think the mystery tap is the solar input.  That's a code approved (though admittedly sketchy looking) way to add a solar system to a panel this old, and there's no solar breakers, so I think it must be that.

Comment: Mostly to save space the area the tank is in very tight. Plus I'm adding a whole house filter and i would love to allocate the space  freed up space for that system

Comment: @WalterMoose -- how big is the existing tank, both in gallonage and physical space? Is there somewhere else a tank could go?

Comment: @WalterMoose -- also, how many square feet is the house, and can you get us a photo of the nameplate on your air conditioner?

Answer (score 2):

With that panel the answer is no way, I can’t read the main breaker value but I would bet your main 150 at max you have a total of 240 amps of breakers ok 200 because we use the larger of heat / ac so 200 and if the existing water heater is 20 it is two small for a full sized tanked water heater. Even if a 200 and I seriously doubt it. Your service is two small. Are you feeding an inside sub with the 60 for lights and receptacles?

Comment: And maybe additional load provisioned for the feeder tap?

Comment: Yes a sub was ran inside.

Comment: Yes a sub was ran inside. I haven't changed anything electrical the wiring was like this when we purchased the house.

Comment: that's a 200A panel (by the label)  and a 200A breaker so far as I can tell (by looking up TQD and M322)

Comment: Walter, the inside label states 200 amp I am surprised that is a large buss for that small of a panel but I would stick with my first sentence NO way you can add 27kw to that panel. If you seriously want this I would suggest going to a 30/40 panel 300 amp continuous and 400 amp peak, or a 320a panel called different things in different areas. This will allow for the addition of the 50 amp car charger that will be needed in the future if we go to electric cars and that size upgrade will be needed for both to be added.

Comment: Class 320 is the local vernacular (for the meter/can - split into a pair of 200A panels.)

Comment: @WalterMoose -- how many square feet is the house, and can you post a photo of the air condtioner's nameplate please? Also, I take it there's not a suitable home for a tank somewhere else in the house...?